# Is there a theoretical basis for using partial least squares with categorical responses

Tags: categorical-data, regularization, categorical-encoding, partial-least-squares

I am using what is called PLS-DA in JMP to find a model for predicting a categorical (Positive/Negative) response.  The documentation says that the responses are simply coded as 0/1, thereby converting the response vector to a vector of numbers, and then standard PLS is applied.  This technique certainly ensures that the response vector (Y) and the linear combination of design matrix columns (X * beta) both are part of an inner product space which is necessary before we can define and therefore maximize the covariance(X * beta, Y).  But what troubles me is that Y is then centered just like the columns of X.  Is there any literature that develops PLS when the response is not coded to be numeric?  It would seem to me that instead of maximizing covariance(X * beta, Y) we might have to maximize the likelihood of Y.  But that would be problematic if X has a great deal of colinearity and PLS doesn't seem to be a regularization technique.  Is simply coding the response an obvious and "legal" thing to do?

Comment: Actually, PLS provides regularization by selecting number of components (aka latent variables). The centering of Y is necessary for mathematical reasons since we are modeling (co)variance. However, if you have an uneven number of samples for each category plain centering can be problematic. Brereton has a very nice paper specifically on this topic: https://doi.org/10.1002/cem.2609

Comment: In short, centering plays a significant role as it corresponds to the decision boundry and and one may want to tweak the mean value so that the decision boundry is put to the right place.

Comment: I agree that PLS can achieve regularization.  I think of PLS, more generally, as a way to generate a orthogonal basis for span(X).  So PLS, when the binary output is re-coded as 0's and 1's, will generate an orthogonal basis for the span(X).  If instead of maximizing Cov(X * Beta, Y) at each step we instead maximize Likelihood(Y | X * Beta) we will generate an orthogonal basis in a different way.  Do these bases agree with one another.  Certainly if they do not agree for the first couple of directions we might expect the two models to have different performance with respect to predicting Y.